# Chrome MediaRecorder API share pre-selected tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, mediarecorder

So, here's is my doubt.
I'm using the MediaRecorder API, to make a recording of my browser's screen. I can capture the whole browser screen + audio(tab) + my microphone. Everything is working fine. But I only need to capture the screen+audio from the tab that started the recording. On that popup thats opens on google chrome, when I want to screenshare some tab or application, is it possible to show only the tab that started the screenshare? So I don't have to seek everytime the tab that I want to share.

I didn't find any information about that.

When working with the google chrome API, I see that we can capture only a tab, but outside this API, is it possible to accomplish something similar? Or is only possible to work with pre-selected tab if I develop a google chrome extension?

```
chrome.tabCapture.capture({audio: true, video: true}, callback);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't specify it or limit it to the current tab.

> Note: Constraints never cause changes to the list of sources available
> for capture by the Screen Sharing API. This ensures that web
> applications can’t force the user to share specific content by
> restricting the source list until only one item is left

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture

Comment: There's now a `preferCurrentTab:true` option in Chromium.